# C# Unassigned Local Variables

Tags: c#

Take this code for example (assume all variables instantiated):

```
if (size > 10)
{    
    width = 5;
    height = 5;    
}
else 
{
    width = 6;
    height = 7;
}    
area = width * height;
```

My issue is if I run code like that for example width and height in the are forumla will give me an error saying "Use of unassigned local variable". How can I make the variables width and height get the values from the if statements to run in the area formula and writeline? I know it has something to do with the variables being out of the scope of the if statements.

Comment: where have you declared width, height, and area?

Comment: Where you initialize `size`?

Comment: In my actual code they have been instantiated

Comment: That means we have to guess the actual code?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

You need to initialize the variables outside the if statement; so they became in the same scope as where they are used.

```
var width = 0;
var height = 0;

if( size > 10){    
    width = 5;
    height = 5;    
}
else {
    width = 6;
    height = 7;
}

area = width * height;
```

Comment: No need to intialize `with` and `height` here. It may be problem with `size`

Comment: The answer is still the same though, that the variables need to be initialised properly.

Comment: In my actual code they have been instantiated

Comment: @eagle560 can you post the actual code then?

Comment: I did not see that my variables were not instantiated correctly (integer instantiated for double) Thank you guys for your help.

Comment: What's up with the downvotes?

Answer (score 3):

> initialize variable before use:

Make sure that you have initialized the  `size` variable before it is using.  variables `width` and `height` are initialized both in if as well as in else so that it should get value in both true condition and false condition.So your code will be like the following:

```
var size =0.0;
// get value for size
if (size > 10)
{    
    width = 5;
    height = 5;    
}
else 
{
    width = 6;
    height = 7;
}    
area = width * height;
```

Or you have to make these variables as global

Comment: No need to intialize `width` and `height` here. It may be problem with `size`

Comment: In my actual code they have been instantiated

Comment: how can we guess that are initialized in actual code?

Comment: In `if - else` you can use unassigned variable because it will must initialize in `if` or `else`. But if you have both `if` no `else` then there will be a possibility that no `if` become `true` so must need to initialize before using.

Answer (score 3):

If your variables are instantiated **within scope of the conditional code OR globally**, then there is no reason why it shouldn't work. However, if they aren't instantiated, you could do the following (**assuming `size` is instantiated with a value as well**).

```
int width = (size > 10) ? 5 : 6;
int height = (size > 10) ? 5 : 7;
int area = height * width;
```

Or you could add a nifty little function like so..

```
private int GetArea(int size)
{
    return ((size > 10) ? 5 : 6) * ((size > 10) ? 5 : 7);
}
```